# Move cell range B-F for odd number rows to cell range G-K on even number rows

Tags: excel

I would like to move a range of cells up 1 row and 5 cells to the right. Here is what I have:

[image]

and here is what I would like to have:

[image]

I realize that I don't have any code/attempts so far, but I'm not even sure where to start with this.

If there is a function I can use in a cell and then drag it down all the rows I want to apply it to that would be great.

Unmerging the cell in A2/A3 isn't a part of the answer, I can do that separately.

**EDIT:**

Currently I have name1 spanning 2 rows. All the data in rows 2 and 3 belong to "name1". I want to move the data from cells B3-F3 to G2-K2. I have already unmerged the name1 A2-A3 range so name1 is entirely in A2.

There are over 800 rows like this, and what I described in the paragraph above will be applied to every other set of rows for "name2", "name3" and so on. In the end, I want to have 400 rows, with columns A-K.

Comment: @urdearboy There are 800 rows. That's why I said I would like something where I apply it to 1 row and drag it down and the formula automatically applies it to all the other rows.

Comment: **I realize that I don't have any code/attempts so far, but I'm not even sure where to start with this.** - start by recording a macro with the actions you want to do.

Comment: @Vityata this only applies to the one row though.

Comment: @Michael - well, it is some kind of a start...

Comment: @urdearboy Not necessarily. It would be nicer to be able to do such things in the front end of excel but VBA would work if nothing else is capable.

Comment: Do the column headings matter?

Comment: @JohnBustos In what sense are you asking if they matter? They can be there or not be there they shouldn't affect the solution

Comment: @urdearboy This is an example as I can't post the sensitive data. There are 800 more rows that look very similar to the one I posted above. In the end I will have 400 rows, and have columns A-K

Comment: Since you're putting data in `col2` in your second row into `col7` in the transform. Does that matter or you just want one row with all the data in it associated with `name1`?

Comment: @urdearboy I updated my question. People don't generally post full pictures of their data. After the first example, the data looks the same throughout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the below code in a module and give it a test. You will need to change "Sheet1" in my code to the sheet name with your data on the 4th line (`Set WS = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Here")` This will not touch your col headers.

1.Determine Last Row
 2. Copy target range (5 width)
 3. offset (-1,5)
 4. Delete target range row
 5. loop until LRow

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveMe()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LRow As Long
LRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim TargetRange as Range
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To LRow
    Set TargetRange = WS.Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 6))
    TargetRange.Copy
    WS.Cells(i, 7).PasteSpecial
    TargetRange.EntireRow.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there is a function I can use in a cell and then drag it down all the rows I want to apply it to that would be great.

In G2, copied across to K2 and then G2:K2 down to suit:

```
=OFFSET(A2,1,1)
```

To tidy up, select the entire sheet, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and, when you have unmerged, Filter and delete the rows that are blank in ColumnA. Drag F1 across to suit.